An Attempt at Creating a Type-Safe, Generic Swap Macro With Compile Time Error Checking
Properties:

It evaluates each of A and B only once (sizeof is special, as it doesn't evaluate its arguments, except for VLAs, which this solution would not work for).
It has a compile-time check for the correct sizes, and prints a nice, user-friendly error message if the sizes are not the same.
It has a compile-time check for compatible types.
It has no naming issue with a hidden variable.
The size of the temporary variable is computed at compile time, so the compound literal is not a dynamic array.
It does not rely on VLAs, so it is more portable.
It does not use declare any local variables.

Drawbacks:

It would not work for variables that are declared with the register storage class. All the folks using register variables in tight loops would not be looking for an extra function call anyway.

It would not work for VLAs, because:

The language prohibits it:


6.5.2.5 Compound literals
Constraints
1 The type name shall specify an object type or an array of
unknown size, but not a variable length array type.


static_assert expects a constant expression.


It would not work for identical variables (one should not be attempting to do that).


Code:
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

/**
 * Like C11's _Static_assert() except that it can be used in an expression.
 *
 * EXPR - The expression to check.
 * MSG  - The string literal of the error message to print only if EXPR evalutes
 *        to false.
 *
 * Always return true. */
#define STATIC_ASSERT_EXPR(EXPR, MSG)   \
    (!!sizeof( struct { static_assert ( (EXPR), MSG ); char c; } ))

void util_memswap(size_t psize,
                  void *restrict p1, 
                  void *restrict p2)
{
    unsigned char *a = p1;
    unsigned char *b = p2;
    unsigned char tmp;

    while (psize--) {
        tmp = *a;
        *a++ = *b;
        *b++ = tmp;
    }
}

#define SWAP(A, B)                                                         \
    util_memswap((sizeof *(1 ? &(A) : &(B))                                \
        * STATIC_ASSERT_EXPR(sizeof (A) == sizeof (B),                     \
        "Arguments of SWAP() must have same size and compatible types.")), \
        &(A),                                                              \
        &(B))

Usage:
int main(void)
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;

    SWAP(a, b);
    assert(a == 20);
    assert(b == 10);

    char s[10] = "hello";
    char t[10] = "world";
    
    SWAP(s, t);
    assert(strcmp(s, "world") == 0);
    assert(strcmp(t, "hello") == 0);
}

Another version of SWAP() can be used that would also work with VLAs. For instance, the original version of @null worked with VLAs too (and when a and b are same, as it uses memmove()):
#define SWAP_GENERIC(A, B) \
    util_memswap(sizeof *(1 ? &(A) : &B), &(A), &(B))

Although this does not have a compile-time check for dissimilar sizes.
References:
I have looked at a myriad of implementations and StackOverflow answers and built on the work of others. Credit where it is due (you'd also find lengthy explanations of the constructs in the code above here):

Jenn Gustedt: Implement generic swap macro in C.
null: Is there a built-in way to swap two variables in C?.
Jan Schultke: Is there a built-in way to swap two variables in C?.
Paul J. Lucas: Handy C/C++ Preprocessor Macros.

Review Request:

Anything. Everything. Problems? Is it robust enough? Can we make it more robust?

Most importantly, the nice error message is only printed when the sizes are different, but not when the types are different. Although the code fails to compile on a type-mismatch, and the compiler prints diagnostic messages about it, they are not very nice. How can I remedy this?

Is the swap_internal() function a candidate for C23's [[reproducible]] attribute specifier sequence? What are the [[reproducible]] and [[unsequenced]] attributes in C23, and when should I use them? says that memcpy() can be reproducible.



"sizeof is special, as it doesn't evaluate its argument" --> Hmm, sure about that?

@chux-ReinstateMonica So VLAs, would they entail any problem, or do they simply contradict the first property of SWAP()?

Have not analyzed the VLA case, I simply see it as not following your assertion.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Fails to compile with "error: compound literal has variable size." and "error: expression in static assertion is not constant". Well well well, no one mentioned that anywhere. I would search around and edit the post.

Why use three memcpy() calls rather than implementing memswap()?

@c19 Pray, what is memswap()? How is it better than the three memcpy() calls? Are you perchance speaking of the function having two memcpy() calls and one memmove() call in the StackOverflow questions I have linked?

I think in your "correct usage" section you forgot to swap array1 and array3

@Harith memswap() is a function which swaps the contents of two blocks of memory, by analogy with memcmp(), memcpy(), memmove() etc. It would only need to read and write each object once, while the three incovations of memcpy() in swap_internal() must read and write the object three times.

@c19 Mhm, I see what you meant now. To answer your question, probably because none of the answers I built on implemented memswap(). It should be trivial to do so nevertheless. There already seems to be one: https://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/3pub/memswap/ But we'd have to profile.

@Aemyl Indeed, copy-paste error. Thank you, I will rectify it.

@c19 Update: memswap() works perfectly. And works for the second variant that allows VLAs too. Thanks.

SWAP(a, b) looks wrong.
The below code looks like the values of a, b are not changed as would be expected with any function foo(a, b) where arguments are passed by value..
int a = 10;
int b = 20;

SWAP(a, b);
// Somewhat surprising to find out a, b have changed.

True that SWAP() is not a function, and is hinted as a macro since it is in capital letters, yet this remains un-C-like syntax.
I'd rather see more C-like code such as below and have the implementation adjusted.
SWAP(&a, &b);


Would changing &(A) and &(B) to (A) and (B) break anything?

@Harith, unclear.  Better to see complete alternative.

Well done avoiding the temptation to name the function memswap() (for readers that don't know, identifiers beginning mem followed by a letter are reserved for future functions belonging to <string.h>).
The implementation of util_memswap() could be improved for larger objects:

while (psize--) {
    tmp = *a;
    *a++ = *b;
    *b++ = tmp;
}


You'll find that your library's version of memcpy() and/or memmove() probably shift larger units according to the target platform's architecture, resorting to byte-by-byte copies only at the ends (and possibly for unaligned data).  A tuned implementation of swap would likely use similar optimisations.
It's unlikely that your compiler's optimiser would recognise the pattern here and group the transfers into larger units.  I tried with latest GCC and Clang - the former did some loop unrolling, but both still generate code that accesses memory in single units as far I can read.

Is the implementation in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/17591624/20017547 defined behavior? I don't like how it casts a void * to a long * and interprets it as a long *. Does it not break strict aliasing rules? Edit: Okay, one comment says that the implementation does not have to follow rules. Could you share a valid portable example with no undefined behavior?

No, library memcpy() and family tend to be targeted towards specific compilers and specific processors (often not even written in C) rather than being portable code.  To be honest, I wouldn't attempt one of those.  You might get a performance boost by using memcpy() to swap a substantial chunk at a time via a buffer that's aligned (e.g. uintmax_t buf[16]; while (psize) { size_t size = min(sizeof buf, psize); memcpy(&buf, a, size); memcpy(a, b, size); memcpy(b, &buf, size);  a += size;  b += size;  psize -= size); }.  Obviously there's still work to do there:...

... The buffer size would need tuning from that 16 according to profile results; I don't know whether uintmax_t is a good way to get it aligned; for small transfers it's probably faster to use the existing char-by-char implementation (again, benchmark to determine the cut-over point, if any - that's probably very platform-dependent).

Toby, " I don't know whether uintmax_t is a good way to get it aligned" --> maxalign_t is sufficient sized object.

To have a type sensitive SWAP take a look at __auto_type and/or typeof ():
    #define SWAP(a,b)          \
    ({                         \
         __auto_type _a = (a); \
         a = b;                \
         b = _a;               \
    })

(This one is really fast but sadly doesn't work with C arrays.)
If you want to stay with what you have, you can also optimize the while loop by partially unrolling it ith a technique known as Duff ’s Device:
    void
    copy (char *restrict to, char *restrict from, size_t count)
    {
        if (count == 0)
            return;
        size_t n = (count + 7) / 8;
        switch (count % 8)
        {
            do {
                case 0: *to++ = *from++;
                case 7: *to++ = *from++;
                case 6: *to++ = *from++;
                case 5: *to++ = *from++;
                case 4: *to++ = *from++;
                case 3: *to++ = *from++;
                case 2: *to++ = *from++;
                case 1: *to++ = *from++;
            } while (--n > 0);
        }
    }

On the other hand, a generic SWAP is kinda not a good idea; the best algorithm might also depend on what you are doing, and it may be better to code it directly. (memswap () is still well optimized for general usage).


I see no need for SWAP() to ever expand to an expression. It also requires a compiler extension. 2) __auto_type is not in ISO C, and with typeof, would incompatible types result in a compilation error? I don't see how what you suggest is an improvement, when it only works under one dialect of C, and does not work for arrays, and does not result in a compilation error. 3) Aren't compilers aware of Duff's device since forever?

